# mysql data compression

Tags: mysql

I have some data in a few columns that repeat often from 40-80%.

Is there some way to have mysql do some kind of compression?

Gordon

Comment: I dont think you want to slow down mySQL like that; An important question is WHY would you want to? Perhaps there is another problem that needs solving instead.

Comment: Can you give us some examples of this data?

Answer (score 1):

Repeating data?  Sounds like you're breaking normalization rules.  I'd investigate those before resorting to compression.  How do you intend to query on compressed data?  Not useful, in my opinion.